# execute npm script from another package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, run-script

Suppose I have 2 node packages, one called `parent` and one called `child`. child has a `package.json` with some scripts.  Is it possible to *include* the scripts from `child` in the context of `parent`?

For example:

child/package.json:

```
"scripts":{
   "hello":"echo hello"
}
```

parent/package.json:

```
"dependencies":{"child":"1.0.0"}
```

Then from the command line in the `parent` directory:

`parent> npm run hello` //outputs hello

Answer (score 0):

You can run child script from parent but not in parent context.

```
{scripts: "cd node_modules/child && npm run-script hello"}
```

Comment: yeah but that runs it in the child directory, i want it to execute it in parent...